# How do I put a reset button on my view's exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views

This a really basic question, but it stumped me for a moment and there was little I could find on the net that answered this most basic need.

By default when you expose filters in a view, the only button that shows is 'Apply'.  I have seen reset buttons elsewhere on the site and on example sites but I don't know how to make it appear on my view.

How do I put a 'Reset' button on my view to reset the exposed filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your view configuration go to Advanced -> EXPOSED FORM -> Exposed form style: Basic | **settings**.
   [image]
2. Check 'Include reset button' and save.
   [image]